# SecurityTokenValidated does not fire in OpenId Authentication with Azure AD

Tags: azure, authentication, openid-connect

I am using OpenId Authentication with Microsoft and with successful authentication I redirect with my custom state attributes in event SecurityTokenValidated but this event does not fire.

I have a seperate sample application in which I have implemented same logic but it is working fine there.

```
SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                {                                                   
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);                      
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
```

Why isn't this event firing?

Comment: How you config it , show entire method

Comment: I noticed that I had not enabled SSL for my return URL. I have resolved the issue. thanks